# Import job configurations into common job configuration class (Annotation config)

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am refactoring a legacy Spring Batch XML based application to use annotation configuration instead. I want to understand how I can convert the following XML files into annotation based configuration and maintain the same separation of concern.

Here is a simple example for the sake of discussion.

**job-config-1.xml**

```
<job id="job1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
               <batch:step id="step1">
                    <batch:tasklet throttle-limit="20" task-executor="taskExecutor">
                        <batch:chunk reader="reader1"
                            writer="writer1" commit-interval="500" />
                    </batch:tasklet>
                </batch:step>
</job>
```

**job-config-2.xml**

```
<job id="job2" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
                   <batch:step id="step2">
                        <batch:tasklet throttle-limit="20" task-executor="taskExecutor">
                            <batch:chunk reader="reader2"
                                writer="writer2" commit-interval="500" />
                        </batch:tasklet>
                    </batch:step>
</job>
```

**job-config-3.xml**

```
<import
        resource="classpath*:/spring/jobs/job-config-1.xml" />
<import
        resource="classpath*:/spring/jobs/job-config-2.xml" />
<batch:job id="jobFlow">

            
    <batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
        <job ref="job1" job-launcher="jobLauncher" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step2">
        <job ref="job2" job-launcher="jobLauncher" />
    </batch:step>
    
</batch:job>
```

What I want to move from XML configuration to Java configuration. I want to create 3 job configuration classes for each of the XMLs. Lets say JobConfig1.java, JobConfig2.java and JobConfig3.java.

JobConfig3.java would import JobConfig1.java and JobConfig2.java; however, I was unable to find an example for this kind of structure in the docs. How do I go about doing this?

Note : I am not looking to use Spring Boot. Just regular Spring Batch through annotation configuration.

Comment: @Atmas Sorry but that doesn't answer my question. Do read my question to understand that I am not asking how to convert XML to annotation config. I am asking how to create a modular job such that two jobs are plugged together to create a third job.

Comment: @Atmas : Yes I am asking something else. Imagine two Spring batch jobs Job1 and Job2 each with 10 steps. and each having their own Spring Configuration class. Now Imagine Job3 that combines Job1 and Job2 into a single consolidated job. Job3 would have it's own Spring Configuration class. If this is not clear, see my XML example. I want to convert each XML file into it's own Configuration class. I think I made that pretty clear.

Comment: @Atmas I know what a flow is. I am asking how two jobs defined in two different Configuration classes can be plugged together into a 3rd job defined in a third configuration class. My question is more about Job bean imports etc and not about Spring Batch flow API. If this comment doesn't still clarify my question and your answer is still "use a flow", then I guess this discussion ends here between you and I because clearly you want to answer a different question. The question I am asking multiple job configs. Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: I have removed my contributions as irrelevant to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent to your XML configuration would be to define each job in its own configuration class, then import those classes in the main job's configuration. Here is a quick example:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
// @Import({Job1Config.class, Job2Config.class}) // use this if the classes where you define sub jobs are not nested
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MainJobConfig {

    @Bean
    public Job mainJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps, Job job1, Job job2, JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        return jobs.get("mainJob")
                .start(steps.get("subJob1").job(job1).launcher(jobLauncher).build())
                .next(steps.get("subJob2").job(job2).launcher(jobLauncher).build())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Configuration
    static class Job1Config {
        // define job 1 artefacts (reader, writer, steps, etc)
        // for simplicity, the step is inlined in the job definition
        @Bean
        public Job job1(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
            return jobs.get("job1")
                    .start(steps.get("job1Step1").tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                        System.out.println("job1");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }).build())
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Job2Config {
        // define job 2 artefacts (reader, writer, steps, etc)
        // for simplicity, the step is inlined in the job definition
        @Bean
        public Job job2(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
            return jobs.get("job2")
                    .start(steps.get("job2Step1").tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                        System.out.println("job2");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }).build())
                    .build();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MainJobConfig.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean("mainJob", Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `JobStep` to define your step for example in your `Job3` the `step1` should look like this :

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").job(context.getBean("job1", Job.class))
            .parametersExtractor(new DefaultJobParametersExtractor()).build();
}
```

from this, you can run `step1` like any other step, but when `job3` will appeal this step all steps of `job1` will be executed. `job1` is a subJob of your principal `job3`.

for job1 his definition should be like this : (the same as JobConfig2)

```
@Configuration
class JobConfig1 {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job job1() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(step1()).build();
    }

    // definition of steps
    public Step step1() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance but I am not sure how this answers the question as well. A slightly more complete example would be helpful to me and other readers.

Comment: Even with the edit, there are still outstanding questions. For example, if you have JobConfig1.java and JobConfig2.java, do you add the EnableBatchProcessing annotation above them? What about JobConfig3.java, should it also have EnableBatchProcessing. A more complete answer would show JobConfig1.java, JobConfig2.java and finally JobConfig3.java assembling the jobs...

Comment: You have only one `EnableBatchProcessing`, that allows your batch beans to be registered like `JobRepository` and for your jobs (JobConfig3.java...) each of them should be annotated with `@Configuration` because it's defines beans that will be registered in a spring container.

Comment: Understood, And where would I put this EnableBatchProcessing? On my main class or on JobConfig3.java? Also, instead of using applicationContext, can't I autowire the Job instances in JobConfig3.java?

Comment: yes you can autowire your job in JobConfig3 but in your example the job1 and job2 are subJobs of job3. for EnableBatchProcessing you put it in your main class

Comment: FYI : EnableBatchProcessing in the main class doesn't work. It has to be added in one of the Configuration classes. Preferably the one that is the lowest level configration class that uses beans defined in other configuration classes. Your answer gave me some direction so +1 for that. I'll post an answer shortly on how I got this done.

Comment: The main class is when you put `SpringBootApplication` annotation that can be used to enable those three features: EnableAutoConfiguration, ComponentScan, and Configuration. from this we can conclude that the main class is a config class where you can define your beans.

Comment: I clearly mentioned in my question that I don't want to use SpringBoot. :). EnableBatchProcessing in main class didn't work even if I made main class a Configuration class.